# Is it possible baking normals and making low poly automatically with a script?

Tags: scripting, normal-map

As in title, I have like 2000 models to decimate, save and bake normals from one to another.
Could a script fulfill such a task? Or I'm asking too much out of scripting?
I don't need a script. but a question if it's possible.
I gladly go and pay later on somewhere for such a thing but I need to know if it's possible.
Thank you for reading and answering

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes it is possible, I have a script which does exactly that.

Short flow:

- Import high poly model
- Duplicate it
- Decimate it (decimate modifier)
- Setup normal map baking material and shader
- Setup Cycles to bake normal map
- Bake original high poly to low poly
- Export low poly

An easy way to create the script is to do the flow in Blender UI and copy the commands from the scripting console.

Comment: Hello and welcome. Can you post sample code of how that works?